# Changing web page elements' appearance by appending extra parameters to URL

Tags: html, css, web, url, dom

Recently I noticed that after searching for some term in Google and browsing the search result, the relevant web page showed my relevant search text as highlighted.

So, I noticed what Google has done is, as sending extra parameters by appending to the URL as `#:~:text=this%20text%20will%20be%20highlighted`.

As an example if I go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow, it shows as follows;

[image]

But when I append `#:~:text=Overflow` to the URL and visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#:~:text=Overflow, then it shows as follows (note that word 'Overflow' is highlighted);

[image]

What I'm wondering is how this behavior is achieved? 
What are such other types of such parameters that we could use?

**Edit:**
My browser is: Microsoft Edge, Version 83.0.478.45 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: is this behaviour only works on some browser?
i tried it works on chrome but not on firefox

Comment: @kirb Actually, I didn't try on firefox but tried it on Chrome and Edge (Chromium) it worked. Is it mean that is it a Chromium feature?

Comment: It's called scroll-to-text-fragment and there are some privacy concerns around it. It's unclear whether Firefox will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some more common and less advanced URL parameters but, I'll post them here anyways:

There are of course Anchor links that can be appended to the URL

```
<!-- https://Example.com/#top -->

<body> 
    <a name="top"> </a>
    <a href="#top">
        Go To Top Of Page
    </a>     
</body>
```

And URL query parameters that can be picked up by the server in a variety of ways, here is a python/Django example

```
# https://Example.com/?variable=someValue

import requests

def page_view(request):
    variableValue = request.GET.get('variable', None)
```